# Meaning of "the domain of the inverse of $y^2+x^2-4=0$ is equal to the range of $f(y)=\sqrt{-y^2+4}$"?

Tags: vector-analysis

https://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Rational-functions/Rational-functions.faq.question.346763.html

says:

> The domain of **the inverse of** $y^2+x^2-4=0$ **is equal to
>   the range** of $f(y)=\sqrt{-y^2+4}$.

Why/where there is the inverse and why is it equal to the range?

Comment: the inverse of the equation $$x^2+y^2=4$$?

Comment: Perhaps they have not actually defined the inverse there (I don't see it). Rather, they merely mean that "if one would consider the inverse, then ...". Since $f^{-1}(f(y))=y=f^{-1}(\sqrt{-y^2+4})=f^{-1}(x)$